# Pipfile is getting created using python 3.9 instead of 3.11

Tags: python-3.x, pipenv

I have started using the pipenv package to manage the virtual environments through VSCode. The problem is whenever I have tried creating a virtual env using the command pipenv shell, it is creating a virtual environment with the Python 3.9 interpreter instead of Python 3.11

Below are the steps that I have taken care of and verified as well:

1. Set the Python 3.11 to PATH variable
2. Before I create the virtual environment path, the interpreter is also set to Python 3.11 from the Python: Select Interpreter settings. Also, tried executing a simple python file in its own directory using the Python 3.11 interpreter. It works fine for the file execution but it doesn't work while creating virtual environment for the same workspace.
3. Set the default python interpreter as Python 3.11 path
4. Provided the path for python.venvPath which contains both the python versions installed in my machine.

Please let me know if there is something else needs to be taken care of as well to resolve the issue. Thanks in advance